# Score calculation, considering negative marking

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to find if I can ask a script to calculate a grade where for each good answer it gives +1, and for each wrong answer it substracts -0,25. The calculation will be made in column C, as shown in the screenshot. In the example, the correct score is 6,25 instead of 7.

BTW, the score calculation refers to the key answers on the row 2.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what the calculation is for wrong answers

Comment: Hope it will be more clear with this screen shot: https://imgur.com/Whg68ph
I added the scores for each answer

Comment: It's not clear.

Comment: How about a simple algebraic equation?

Comment: this will be a google forms sheet report.

Comment: Can I ask you about your logic for retrieving the value of `6.25`?  1. About deciding `good answer` and `wrong answer`, which do you want to use the background color or the row 2? 2. I think that it might be difficult to find the script for directly resolving your goal. So how about creating a script instead of searching? 3. About `the score calculation refers to the key answers on the row B`, `row B` is the row 2?

Comment: Hi Tanaike: 1.I'd like to use a color code, green for good answer and orange for wrong, cell formating could be a solution. 2. I'm trying to find a way that the "Yes", "No" would be converted to numbers: 1 if good and -0,25 if wrong, then, a sum will be done at column C. 3. Indeed, row 2. My apologies.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide the actual color codes of `green for good answer and orange for wrong` as the hex values? Because I couldn't know them from your question. By the way, when the referring answer of the row 2 can be used, I think that it will also be useful for calculating the values. How about this?

Comment: Orange = #ff9900 / Green = #3ace9c . For the other part of your question, I think it is a relevant way to go. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed 2 sample scripts as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to calculate for the values of column "C" by checking the background colors of each cell using Google Apps Script.

  - When the background color of cell is `#3ace9c` (green), you want to add `1`.
  - When the background color of cell is `#ff9900` (orange), you want to reduce `0.25`.
- You want to calculate for the values of column "C" by comparing the columns "D" to "M" at the row 2 (the referring answer) and each row (after row 3) using Google Apps Script.

  - When the columns "D" to "M" at the row 2 are the same with each row, you want to add `1`.
  - When the columns "D" to "M" at the row 2 are NOT the same with each row, you want to reduce `0.25`.

For this, how about this answer?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the background colors are used. The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Prepare an object including the color codes for "good" and "wrong" answers.
2. Retrieve the background colors from the range of "D3:M" in the sheet.
3. Calculate the values using the object and the background colors.
4. Put the values to the column "C" in the sheet.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.

  // 1. Prepare an object including the color codes for "good" and "wrong" answers.
  const obj = {"#3ace9c": 1, "#ff9900": -0.25};  // Please set the color codes, if you change the color.

  // 2. Retrieve the background colors from the range of "D3:M" in the sheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const backgrounds = sheet.getRange("D3:M" + sheet.getLastRow()).getBackgrounds();

  // 3. Calculate the values using the object and the background colors.
  const result = backgrounds.map(r => [r.reduce((c, e) => c += obj[e], 0)]);

  // 4. Put the values to the column "C" in the sheet.
  sheet.getRange(3, 3, result.length, 1).setValues(result);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the referring answer of the row 2 is used. The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve values from the range of "A2:M" in the sheet.
2. Retrieve the referring answer.
3. Calculate the values of each values by comparing the referring answer, and create an array including the result values.
4. Put the values to the column "C" in the sheet.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.
  
  // 1. Retrieve values from the range of "A2:M" in the sheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:M" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 2. Retrieve the referring answer.
  const answers = values.shift();
  answers.splice(0, 3);

  // 3. Calculate the values of each values by comparing the referring answer, and create an array including the result values.
  const result = values.map(([,,c,...dm]) => [dm.reduce((c, e, i) => e == answers[i] ? c + 1 : c - 0.25, 0)]);

  // 4. Put the values to the column "C" in the sheet.
  sheet.getRange(3, 3, result.length, 1).setValues(result);
}
```

### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getBackgrounds())
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thank so much, it works!. I have other questions if you don't mind: 1. is it possible to display the result with decimals, because Google Forms doesn't do it by default (https://imgur.com/ZoSBBT2) 2.Can you correct me if I'm wrong, but to format a cell with color that I'm putting this formula: =D3=D2 » then set a color green, and if not =D3<>D2 » orange, is it correct ?

Comment: @Mous Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But from your replying, I cannot understand about your question. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your new question, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve the various issues, immediately. I would like to study more.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike: Thank you for replying. For your information, I added this bit of code to format the column C: https://imgur.com/4hB6DeH

Comment: @Mous Thank you for replying and the additional information. If your new question was resolved by your additional script, I'm glad.

Comment: Last question: if the respondant prefer to leave blank a question, what I need to modify in the code to calculate 0 instead of -0,25 ?

Comment: @Mous Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About your new question, I cannot understand about the situation of `blank a question`. In order to correctly understand about your new question, can you provide the detail information? 1. At first, which sample script are you using now? 2. What is the meaning of `blank a question`?

Comment: I’m using the 2nd script. A blank question means,  the respondant doesn’t answer. He makes no choice between Yes or No.

Comment: @Mous Thank you for replying. In that case, how about modifying from `e == answers[i] ? c + 1 : c - 0.25` to `e == "" ? c : e == answers[i] ? c + 1 : c - 0.25`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216853/discussion-between-mous-and-tanaike).